# NSDate Organization

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, nsdate

I'm attempting to display timestamps in the S, M, H format however I get negative numbers on some accounts of the Minutes format. Better shown than said:

[image]

The tweet by Chris is supposed to be 4m and the tweet by Mina is supposed to be 6m. Here is my implementation code:

```
// Set Timestamp
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[entry[@"created_time"] doubleValue]];
NSDate *currentDateNTime = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *instacomponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date];
NSInteger instahour = [instacomponents hour];
NSInteger instaminute = [instacomponents minute];
NSInteger instasecond = [instacomponents second];
NSDateComponents *realcomponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:currentDateNTime];
NSInteger realhour = [realcomponents hour];
NSInteger realminute = [realcomponents minute];
NSInteger realsecond = [realcomponents second];

NSInteger hour = realhour - instahour;
NSInteger minute = realminute - instaminute;
NSInteger second = realsecond - instasecond;

int adjustedSeconds = ((int)minute * 60) - abs((int)second);
int adjustedMinutes = adjustedSeconds / 60;

if (hour==1 > minute > 0) {
    int negmin = ((int)hour * 60) - abs((int)minute);
    int posmin = abs(negmin);
    NSString *strInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm",posmin];
    cell.timeAgo.text = strInt;
}else if (hour>0){
    NSString *strInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldh",(long)hour];
    cell.timeAgo.text = strInt;
}else if (hour==1){
    NSString *strInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldh",(long)hour];
    cell.timeAgo.text = strInt;
}else if(minute == 1 > second){
    NSString *strInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lds",(long)second];
    cell.timeAgo.text = strInt;
}else{
    NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm",adjustedMinutes];
    cell.timeAgo.text = strFromInt;
}
```

Comment: What does `minute == 1 > second` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One main reason of happening this is timezone.

Try to set the time zone to GMT & then after do you calculation. Hope it helps.